# Python recursion with compound interest

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to build a recursive function in Python for finding the compound interest. This is my code so far.

```
def compound_interest(principal, rate, years):
    return principal*(1 + rate)**years

def compound_interest_recursive(principal, rate, years)
    if years == 0:
        return principle
    else:
        return 



principal_str = input("Enter the principal ")
principal = int(principal_str)

rate_float = input("Enter the interest rate ")
rate = float(rate_float)

years_str = input("Enter the number of years ")
years = int(years_str)

print("Principal after", years,"year(s) is",compound_interest\
      (principal, rate, years))
```

Can someone help by telling me what I am missing? Thanks. I am trying to get it to input the numbers and then print it out.

Comment: Well, what does your code do now? What's wrong with it?

Comment: yes the formula is P(1+i)^n for P= principle, i = interest, and n=years

Comment: @Marcin Look at it: it doen't do the recursion at all.

Comment: Hint: What is the return after 1 more year of compounding?

Comment: Tip: the spelling of variables matters.

Comment: just wondering how to make it recursive. I know it isnt right now

Comment: As a general note, recursion tends to lead to unreadable, unintuitive and brittle code of limited functionality. Don't make code recursive just to make it recursive outside of homework problems like this.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're doing it recursively as a programming exercise - it can also be done with [Maths™](http://www.mathsisfun.com/money/compound-interest.html).

It looks to me like you're not calling `compound_interest_recursive()` anywhere recursively. Recursion is (and I'm simplifying a little here) a call to a function from within itself. Looks to me like you just want this:

```
def compound_interest_recursive(principal, rate, years):
    if years == 0:
        return principal
    else:
        return compound_interest_recursive(principal * rate, rate, years-1)
```

This code assumes that rate is expressed as a ratio - for example, 15% would be `1.15`.

This is the coding equivalent of the following statements:

- The compound after zero years is the same as the principal.
- The compound interest after N years is the compound interest after N-1 years multiplied by the interest rate.

So you can see that to use recursion you need to break your problem down to a *base case*, where you can stop the recursion, and a *recursive step*, where you can define the problem in terms of a simpler problem. In this example our base case is that after zero years there's no change to the principal and the recursive step is that each year we apply the rate once to the principal of the previous year. It's really important to make sure your recursion always *terminates* - i.e. the result of applying the recusive step will always eventually lead to a base case.

Note that in more complicated problems you may have multiple different base cases and also potentially multiple different recursive steps. You can also have more complex recursions where a set of related functions call each other, although if you make things *too* complicated it becomes very difficult to convince yourself you don't have issues like infinite recursions.

Also one final point is that Python has a limit of 1000 recursive calls (by default) so you can't use this for problems which involve a lot of recursion. For example, compound interest over 1000 years won't work with this approach. This is because every time you make a recursive call, you consume a little bit more memory and eventually you will run out of memory. Python protects you against running out of memory in this way by putting a simple limit on the number of recursive calls, on the basis that if you're recursing more than 1000 deep then the chances are something's gone wrong. Typically you should avoid recursive approaches if you expect to be going more than, say 50-100 levels deep, but that's a subjective issue.

If this is a problem, you can often implement recursive problems as *iterative* ones such as this example:

```
def compound_interest_iterative(principal, rate, years):
    for i in range(years):
        principal *= rate
    return principal
```

Of course in your case the simple formula is the best approach, but in more complex problems an iterative solution such as the one above will typically consume less memory and run (slightly) faster than a recursive one. The flip side is that it can be harder to write iterative code than recursive code for some types of problem.

Comment: `compound_interest_recursive` is the function he's having trouble writing. `compound_interest` is the version that just uses Math.

Comment: Yeah, spot the stupid mistake (now fixed) of not decrementing `years`. Also changing name of function as Barmar pointed out this is the alternate version...

Comment: I know people have different philosophies about SO. I was hoping not to spoon-feed him the answer, as I don't think people really "get" this unless they have to put it together themselves.

Comment: @Barmar perhaps you're right, although it is subjective. Personally I turn to SO when I've exhausted all the possibilities for my own experimentation and generally I find it helpful to see as many examples as I can get my hands on and an explanation of them - then I can extrapolate to different problems. It's true everyone learns differently, though.

Comment: For your recursive example, I think the correct recursive call is `return compound_interest_recursive(principal*(1+rate), rate, years-1)`

Comment: @drewk: It's just a matter of the interface. I've assumed that the rate is expressed as a ratio, as I mentioned in my answer. If it's expressed as a bare percentage, then yes you need to add `1` to get the ratio. It's just about presenting the function that the caller will find most convenient.

Comment: @Cartroo: Yes, I assumed a bare percentage since this is the interface of Excel. Just a matter of convention I suppose. +1 tho. Nice answer.

Comment: Ok so I use it in the original code and if I call print on it, like

Comment: print(compound_interest_recursive(principal,rate,years)) it will print the interest added. Where do I add it to the original principal?

Comment: It seems to work when I did principal*(1+rate),rate, years-1, so maybe I answered my  own question.

Comment: If your rate is a fraction (i.e. between 0 and 1) then yes, you'll need to +1 to it to get the ratio you need to multiply by. You don't need to *add* anything to the principal unless you're making regular deposits (if this is a savings account) or withdrawls (if this is a loan account), you just need to multiply by the ratio. Anyway, sounds like you have it working, which is great.

Answer (score -2):

```
def compound_interest(prin,rate,year):
    if year<=0:

        return prin
    else:
        return compound_interest(prin+prin*rate/100,rate,year-1)

 compound_interest(100000,12,3)
 140492.8
```

Comment: You need to add some kind of clarification/justification for the code written here.